# How do I make elements render upon loading the page when using conditional rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

At the moment my elements only render upon hard reset I think its because on load my state is set to Null, IDK how to make it so that my divs are stored what's the easiest/best way?

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            healthData: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.state.healthData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data'))
    }


    render() {
        //gets users data and renders it to <p> items
        const healthData = this.state.healthData;
        console.log(healthData);
        return healthData == null ? "" : (
            <div className='main_Main'>
                <div className='meal_divs'>
                    <p className='food_heading'>Status:</p>
                    <p className='food_text'>Your age is: {this.state.healthData.age}</p>
                    <p className='food_text'>Your gender is: {healthData.gender}</p>
                    <p className='food_text'>Your goal is: {healthData.goal}</p>
                    <p className='food_text'>Your height is: {healthData.height}</p>
                    <p className='food_text'>your weight is: {healthData.weight}</p>
                </div>
```

please help

Update: seems to be error with login/signout upon logout user_data and user are moved from local storage then readded upon signing, this is my app once signed in you can see the console logs and the fact that there's nothing wrong with my router.(ignore horrible/broken styles I haven't styled it yet)
[image: page straight after login]
[image: Page after login and hard reset]

conditional rendering on router:

```
  {this.state.user ? (
      < Switch >
        <Route path='/setup_page' component={setup_page} exact />,
        <Route path='/settings_page' component={settings_page} exact />,
        <Route path='/' component={Main_page} />
      </Switch>
    ) : (<Login_page/>)}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "storing" your divs?

Comment: actually, you probably want to read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({healthData: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data'))})
}
```

React doesn't know that state is updated and component should be re-rendered if you are not using `setState`.

Comment: thank you hope this fixes my issue will try now silly of me not using setState

Comment: this didn't change any of the function of my code but definitely a better way to do it

Comment: Mutating state object with assignment `=` is a bad practice which leads to bugs. Always use `setState` for updating state. Good read: https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/

Answer (score 1):

You have a few things that could be causing issues.

1. You are not using `setState()` in your `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ 
        healthData: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data'))
    });
}
```

2. You could benefit from using the syntax `healthData && <div />` in your `render()`

```
render() {
    //gets users data and renders it to <p> items
    const healthData = this.state.healthData;
    return healthData && <div className='main_Main'>...</div>;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'm confused why && would be beneficial? I want to render my <div> if health data is not underfinded/null why would this help?

Comment: Maybe my words were misguided, but here is [some documentation around conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator). It is another option aside from the traditional ternary or if...else conditions

Comment: Thanks I will have a read through always glad to learn new ways of doing stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You are directly mutating the state in your componentDidMount method. This is not intended in react. Instead, you set the state using setState method and the component shall re-render.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.setstate({healthData : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data'))})
}
```

In your render method, you can use object destructing to hold your state health data like below and edit the following code in conditional rendering as below -

```
const { healthData } = this.state;
return(
  <div className='main_Main'>
       <div className='meal_divs'>
   {
      healthData === null ? "" : 
      (
          <p className='food_heading'>Status:</p>
          <p className='food_text'>Your age is: {healthData.age}</p>
          <p className='food_text'>Your gender is: {healthData.gender}</p>
          <p className='food_text'>Your goal is: {healthData.goal}</p>
          <p className='food_text'>Your height is: {healthData.height}</p>
          <p className='food_text'>your weight is: {healthData.weight}</p>
       )
    }
 </div>
 </div>
```